# graphql query return object with null id

Tags: mongodb, graphql, aggregate

Graphql return Oject with null id.
with mongodb.

It looks strange to me.

If I delete `new GraphQLNonNull()` on MailType id,
It works with `id: null`, another fields working fine.

```
const MailType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mail',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID), },
...
})

const Query = {
    mails: {
        type: new GraphQLList(MailType),
        args: {
            senderId: { type: GraphQLID },
            isOffline: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
        },
        async resolve(root, args, req, ctx) {
            if (args.isOffline === false) {
                let a = await model.aggregate([
                  { $match: { isOffline: false } },
                ]);
                let b = await model.find({ isOffline: false });

                console.log(JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.Stringify(b)) /// return true
                return a // error
                return b // working
            }
            return model.find({senderId: args.senderId});
        }
    }
}
```

```
// with a
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mail.id."
        }]
```

I am in trouble for 2 hours but I do not get the answer.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: It simply means that id field is null when you return `a`, which shouldn't be because you have defined id as `GraphQLNonNull` and hence the error.

Comment: @Boney a, b is array of mail. Both have mails with valid id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a mistake in your mongodb schema, not in graphQl.
make sure you did not define you id by `id` key, it should be `_id`.

for example if you are using mongoose it can be something like this:

```
const MailSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  ....
  ....
});
```